# Why does ofstream("log.txt", ios::app|ios::trunc); always fail?

Tags: c++, iostream

The following code was compiled with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP on Windows 7 x64.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("log.txt", ios::app|ios::trunc);
    if (!fout)
    {
        cout << "An error occurred!" << endl; // Always go here! Why?
    }
}
```

[The cppreference.com website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) doesn't say that `ios::app` cannot be combined with `ios::trunc`.

What are the **exact** semantics of `ios::app` and `ios::trunc`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that `ios::app` cannot be combined with `ios::trunc`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? std::ios::trunc basically discards everything while std::ios::app appends.

Comment: @CLearner, just for logging. Delete old contents and append new texts.

Comment: It doesn't say it can't be combined but it does say it's implementation defined.

Comment: @C. Lang, even if it is implementation-defined, I also think it is incorrectly implemented. Because `ios::app|ios::trunc` is meaningful in certain cases.

Comment: @Jim, VC++ Nov 2012 CTP on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I agree, I imagine many could use it but I have to say I see the logic behind not allowing it. It forces the implementation to make decisions in an unclear situation, IMO, of course. `ios::app|ios::trunc` are open modes that determine what state the stream opens in, and they seem somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @JimBalter What's "baseless" about a verbatim quote from the standard?

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by "the documentation". C++ has no centralised documentation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, The "documentation" I just said is at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: You didn't say that. I will edit this link into your question. Please cite your sources in future.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "What's "baseless" about a verbatim quote from the standard? " -- That's not what I referred to; I referred to the only answer that had been posted when I made my comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C++ _does_ have one official documentation: ISO 14882.  There's no point in linking to other sites when asking questions purely about C++; the language is defined by the standard.  (Of course, many questions involve specifics of one or more compilers, and not just purely the language.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Other than referring to the standard as "documentation", I agree of course :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `filebuf` constructor to which these flags are passed<sup>†</sup> has behaviours based on those flags defined in Table 132 in C++11:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|     ios_base flag combination     |  stdio equivalent |
| binary  in    out    trunc    app |                   |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|               +                   |  "w"              |
|               +               +   |  "a"              |
|                               +   |  "a"              |
|               +       +           |  "w"              |
|        +                          |  "r"              |
|        +      +                   |  "r+"             |
|        +      +       +           |  "w+"             |
|        +      +               +   |  "a+"             |
|        +                      +   |  "a+"             |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|   +           +                   |  "wb"             |
|   +           +               +   |  "ab"             |
|   +                           +   |  "ab"             |
|   +           +       +           |  "wb"             |
|   +    +                          |  "rb"             |
|   +    +      +                   |  "r+b"            |
|   +    +      +       +           |  "w+b"            |
|   +    +      +               +   |  "a+b"            |
|   +    +                      +   |  "a+b"            |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, your flag combination is *not* found in that table.

> `[C++11: 27.9.1.4/2]:` *[..]* If `mode` is not some combination of flags shown in the table then the open fails.

Those are the semantics.

<sup><sup>†</sup> `[C++11: 27.9.1.7/2]` & `[C++11: 27.9.1.11/2]` show us that the mode is passed from the stream object to the buffer object.</sup>

Comment: This is a good answer. However, here I would like to give Bo Persson credit, because he is the first of those who give correct answers. His answer is a piece of comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @xmllmx That comment has now been removed by a moderator's blunt ax.

Comment: Cannot help but break into laughter. "wb" is so much less confusing than the fstream conventions.

Answer (score 6):

- **app** (=append): set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation
- **trunc** (=truncate) any current content is discarded, assuming a length of zero on opening.

As you can see, it doesn't make sense to put both together.

Comment: Please keep comments to asking clarifying questions on and answer.  Extended discussion about a particular topic should be kept to [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com). Also, discussions that devolve into namecalling will be removed.